# Calling a function once after threshold without using flags in objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am designing a game in objective C where a player earns money by answering correctly some questions. I am trying to display a congratulation message only once when he reaches a threshold ( every $1000 for example ). I know I can use flags like in the code below:

```
if (money>threshold){
    if (congratMsgShown==NO){
    [self displayCongratMsg];
    congratMsgShown=YES;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that it works only with one threshold. As my player can earn up to $1M, I would have to use 1000 flags like the congratMsgShown. Is there a method in Objective C to call a function only once when a threshold has been reached?
Cheers

Comment: As James Webster suggests, your "flag" just becomes an integer (or float, if more appropriate) that indicates *which* threshold was last reached (or which is yet to be reached, if you prefer).  Certainly doesn't require any razzle-dazzle special function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the same method and changing the threshold?

```
if (money > threshold)
{
    if (congratMsgShown==NO)
    {
        [self displayCongratMsg];
        congratMsgShown=YES;
        threshold += 1000;      //Change the threshold
        //threshold *= 2;       //Example
    }
}
```